# Stereoscopic image in Game mode looks distorted in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

[image: **GameImage**]

This is image that I'm getting in Game mode. I'm using the latest GoogleVR for Unity available as of today and Unity 5.6.0b7. How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that v5.6.0 is a beta version and it is not very suitable for development.

As suggested in the Unity [Forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/google-vr-sdk-1-10-unity-5-5-broken.445323/) - For VR development it's better to stick to using Unity 5.4.2 with Google VR SDK 10.3.

Comment: If you headed at the Google VR Library from google, then you would have been pointed to the latest unity beta version, which is why me, and others, downloaded it. Your answer is not specific to the posted problem, but more oriented to a generic probable cause of bugs.

Comment: I'm using the said version because of inbuilt Cardboard and Daydream features.. I earlier tried generating a build for this app in 5.5.0f3 but it failed due to an error of android manifest which I couldn't figure out how to solve so I downloaded the latest verions of both and rebuilt the whole damn thing..
I read no version later than SDK 1.0 for Google VR was actually stable..
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/google-vr-sdk-1-10-unity-5-5-broken.445323/
Its really becoming a pain in ass.. Would appreciate if you could tell, what last version of both the platforms generate a stable build?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Github issue #451 gvr-unity-sdk on this subject.

Here's the code changes required -

*** Please use the github diff if you know how 
OR
Use my code below - WARNING my code with replace yours so if you haven't made any mods it should be safe.  I'm using GVR 1.20

I've uploaded the files with the code changes here to help.

They both go in Assets\GoogleVR\Scripts\Legacy\Internal\

http://drewfx.com/public/stackoverflow/

Gvreye.cs
StereoRenderEffect.cs

Let me know if you get stuck

Comment: Offtopic:  but I've found that using Unity 5.6.0b10 + GVR 1.20 when I put a move script on the camera, the camera moves fine in Unity but on and Android phone (Galaxy S6) it doesn't move.  I am investigated this issue.

Comment: Here's the link for further clarification about the distortion issue:. https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/451